# Resetting time.clock()

Tags: python, timer, pygame, clock

I'm writing a basic game where you use the mouse to dodge stars, but I can't get a certain part to work properly.

I'm trying to make it so that after 10 seconds of playing you beat the stage and if you lose, the 10 second timer resets.

Here is what I'm trying:

```
def time_pass(self):
        self.time_passed = time.clock()
        print self.time_passed
    if self.time_passed > 10:
        self.state = 3
```

This method only runs `if self.state == 2` which is the main game, and `if self.state == 3` you win, and the losing screen is `if self.state == 0`. But what happens is I run the game and when I click play it runs self.state 2 and starts the timer, and if I lose the timer keeps going. So then when I go back to the main screen and press play again, it picks up where the timer left off instead of resetting.

If you want to see the full game code:

[Star Dodger Git](https://github.com/C-Dubb/StarDodger)

Thanks in advance.

-ChristianCareaga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the time into say `start_time` when you set `self.state = 2`.
Change `self.time_passed > 10:` to `if self.time_passed > (start_time + 10):`
The game will end `10` after starting.
IOW, don't reset the clock.

Comment: Alright im trying a couple things like that but i cant seem to get it im trying to assign `start_time = time.clock()` with out looping it but i dont know how becuase if that loops `start_time` will always = `time_passed`

Comment: Are you doing `start_time = time.clock()` next to your `if self.player_r.colliderect(... self.state = 2`?

Comment: Yesssss i got it perfect Thank You!!

Comment: I use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which gives milliseconds. So if, `now - last >= cooldown: do_stuff()`